# Placing timer ID into its function

Tags: javascript, closures

I would like to put timer ID, returned by setInterval(), into its function:

```
delay_timeout = setInterval(function () {
    test_delay(data['time'], delay_timeout);
}, 1000);
```

Is it possible? To my mind **delay_timeout** doesn't have a value at this point...

I don't want to save **delay_timeout** globally for using later in timer's function to stop it. Several timers may work at the same time.

UPDATE:

Code is not global, it is located here:

```
socket.on('test_delay', function (data) {
    ...
});
```

The point is not to make **delay_timeout** global and be able to kill timer by some condition within its callback function.

Comment: Don't get what you are trying to do. The set interval id is goes into delay_timeout variable.

Comment: Since, at this scope, delay_timeout is a global variable, you can reference it inside of setInterval's function. Is that the question? Or can you clarify?

Comment: I want to be able to stop timer via clearInterval() method WITHIN test_delay(), by some condition. How can I do it, considering delay_timeout WILL NOT be in test_delay() scope?

Comment: @thanksd delay_timeout is not a global. This code located in other function.

Comment: Sure, but it still has that reference relative to whatever function it's in. You can definitely call clearInterval on the id within the setInterval function. https://jsfiddle.net/8m3y6tu8/

Comment: @thanksd Thanks, here is a bit closer solution to what I need: http://jsfiddle.net/gdxxbvf2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code works fine if you put the `setTimeout` call in it's own function like this:

```
function setTimer(){
    var timeId = setTimeout(function(){ console.log(timeId); }, 1);
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
    setTimer();
}
```

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2rg08rh/3/)

The delay_timeout variable is available to your callback as it is in the same enclosure.

So long as you are not in the same context and rerun your `setTimeout` before it has triggered the callback you will be fine. so this won't work:

```
var timeId;

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
     timeId = setTimeout(function(){ console.log(timeId); }, 1);
}
```

(see the second half of the fiddle...)